# Overloading SaveChanges to preserve prior values

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

I am attempting to implement an audit trail of sorts in various tables in my dbContext.

Instead of any changes being overwritten by SaveChanges, I'd like the existing record to be flagged as 'old' and a new record generated flagged as 'current' (recorded together with the user that made the change).  This therefore gives me an audit trail of sorts.

My current approach is to override/overload SaveChanges and then work with the ChangeTracker entries:

```
Public Overrides Function SaveChanges() As Integer
    Throw New InvalidOperationException("User ID must be provided")
End Function

Public Overloads Function SaveChanges(userID As String) As Integer
        Dim recordsUpdated as integer=0

        For Each entry As dbentityentry In Me.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(Function(e) e.State <> EntityState.Unchanged)
            Dim Original As DbPropertyValues = entry.OriginalValues
            Dim Current As DbPropertyValues = entry.CurrentValues

            Dim t As Type = entry.Entity.GetType
            Dim x = Activator.CreateInstance(t) 'create new entity of same type as original
            x=.....

' Am stuck here... I'm trying to create a new record of the same entity type as the original 
'which I will then append to the dbContext/entity, set a field as 'current' and save.  
'Meanwhile I'll change the old field's status to 'old' and MyBase.SaveChanges that.

       Next 'loop through the changes

        'record how many fields were different/had changed
        For Each PropertyName In Original.PropertyNames
            Dim OriginalValue As Object = Original.GetValue(Of Object)(PropertyName)
            Dim CurrentValue As Object = Current.GetValue(Of Object)(PropertyName)
            If Not Object.Equals(OriginalValue, CurrentValue) Then
                recordsUpdated+=1
            End If
        Next
    Next
    MyBase.SaveChanges()
    'Save journal entries

    Return recordsUpdated
End Function
```

Conceptually I'm struggling with how to generically create a new record in an entity when I don't necessarily know what type the entity is (ie which table I'm saving changes to).

Is the Activator.CreateInstance the right approach?  Or will I have to resort to testing for each entity and hardcoding the new record creation?

**UPDATE 1**

Thanks to hjb and Gert I think I'm on the right lines - I'm just not quite seeing the behaviour I'm expecting.  The overloaded SaveChanges is now:

```
 Public Overloads Function SaveChanges(userID As Integer) As Integer
    Dim recordsUpdated As Integer = 0

    For Each entry As dbentityentry In Me.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(Function(e) e.State <> EntityState.Unchanged)

        Dim Original As DbPropertyValues = entry.OriginalValues
        Dim Current As DbPropertyValues = entry.CurrentValues
        Dim NewValues As DbPropertyValues = Current 'NewValue will go into the brand new record (with status='current')

        Dim t As Type = entry.Entity.GetType
        Dim EntityDBSet = Me.Set(t)
       entry.CurrentValues.SetValues(entry.OriginalValues) '<--we don't actually want to change the old record other than set status to 'old'

        Dim NewRow = EntityDBSet.Create 'here's our new row created

        NewValues("Creator") = Convert.ToInt64(userID)
        NewValues("Status")="Current" '<-- indicates the new current data item
        Current("Status")="Old" '<-- indicates it's a previous version

        NewRow = NewValues.ToObject '<--- put the NewValues into a row object to add to table

        'Now append the newly created row
        EntityDBSet.Add(NewRow)
    Next
    MyBase.SaveChanges() 'save the old row (now with status 'old') together with the newly created row (with status 'current')

    Return recordsUpdated
End Function
```

I've removed the counting of records just to make this more concise.

I'm seeing a new row being added but it is merely a copy of the old row - no changes are being made to the old 'current' row and the new row doesn't reflect any of the changes made to the data before the original SaveChanges was called.

Could it be something to do with 'Dim NewValues As DbPropertyValues = Current' - Should I instantiate a new NewValues somehow?  And if so how?

**UPDATE 2 - SOLVED!**

I had suspected that I needed a fresh new object for NewValues and of course the way to instantiate this is to use .ToObject.  So I therefore have:

```
     Public Overloads Function SaveChanges(userID As Integer) As Integer
    Dim recordsUpdated As Integer = 0

    For Each entry As dbentityentry In Me.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(Function(e) e.State <> EntityState.Unchanged)

        Dim Original As DbPropertyValues = entry.OriginalValues
        Dim Current As DbPropertyValues = entry.CurrentValues
        Dim NewValues = Current.ToObject 'NewValue will go into the brand new record (with status='current')

        Dim t As Type = entry.Entity.GetType
        Dim EntityDBSet = Me.Set(t)
       entry.CurrentValues.SetValues(entry.OriginalValues) '<--we don't actually want to change the old record other than set status to 'old'
        Current("Status")="Old" '<-- indicates it's a previous version

        Dim NewRow = EntityDBSet.Create 'here's our new row created

        NewValues("Creator") = Convert.ToInt64(userID)
        NewValues("Status")="Current" '<-- indicates the new current data item

        NewRow = NewValues.ToObject '<--- put the NewValues into a row object to add to table

        'Now append the newly created row
        EntityDBSet.Add(NewRow)
    Next
    MyBase.SaveChanges() 'save the old row (now with status 'old') together with the newly created row (with status 'current')

    Return recordsUpdated
End Function
```

Bingo! - this works.

Comment: So there's always only one history record? If so, that's almost useless as audit trail.

Comment: No - records are never deleted - every state the table has been in will be recorded but only one will have a 'status' of 'current'.  When an update is made, the 'current' record is set to 'old' (along with all the prior versions) and a new one created.

Comment: OK. Maybe `CurrentValues.ToObject()` can help you.

Comment: Yes great thanks! I think this is what I need to transfer the values from the old 'updating' row to the brand new 'current' row.  I've added an update to my question as I'm still not quite getting the behaviour I'm after

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you want to go down this path. The first problem that comes to mind is how to handle entity relationships (one-to-many, one-to-one or many-to-many)?

Instead of doing Activator.CreateInstance, you should use the [DbContext.Set](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679544.aspx) method to get the DbSet and then call [DbSet.Create](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679504.aspx) to have it create an instance of the entity.

---

You can use something similar to the below code to copy the original values of the modified entity to a new 'Audit' entity. I create an entity with the name "Hi" and save it. After it's saved, I change the name and create an 'Audit' object to store the original values.

Also, in the past, I've done auditing by using triggers to copy the original records of a modified row to a different table. E.x.: I would have a table called CompanyHistory and a trigger would copy the original values of the modified row in the Company table to the CompanyHistory table. It also has columns to store who made the change, when, from what machine and the time of the change. I used the [SMO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162169.aspx) library to generate most of the triggers in c#.

```
using (var dbContext = new MyDbContext())
{
    dbContext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = true;
    dbContext.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;
    dbContext.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
```

```
var company = dbContext.Companies.Add(dbContext.Companies.Create());
company.name = "HI";
dbContext.SaveChanges();
company.name = "dfsf";

var updatedEntities = dbContext.ChangeTracker
    .Entries()
    .Where(obj => obj.State == System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified)
    .ToArray();

foreach (var updatedEntity in updatedEntities)
{
    var dbSet = dbContext.Set(updatedEntity.Entity.GetType());
    var auditEntity = dbSet.Add(dbSet.Create());

    var auditEntityEntry = dbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(obj => obj.Entity == auditEntity).First();
    auditEntityEntry.CurrentValues.SetValues(updatedEntity.OriginalValues);
}
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

}

Comment: Thank you - yes this sounds much more promising.

But then how do I update the fields of the unknown entity type?  I'd like to do something like:

     Dim t As Type = entry.Entity.GetType
     Dim EntityDBSet = Me.Set(t)
     Dim NewRow = EntityDBSet.Create
     NewRow("Status").value="Current" '<--set field values in the new record

NewRow is simply of type Object at design-time obviously?

Comment: Great thanks! - yes I need to write the original values back into the the current values and set status to 'old'.  I've updated my question as now neither the updated old nor new record are saving to the DB which I think your answer is indicating they should?